# Linux pipe bad behavior

Tags: c, linux, input, pipe

I have this linux program that uses a pipe to transmit data from the parent to child, and give an answer based on the returned value;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


int fd[2], nbytes;
pid_t childpid;
char readbuffer[80];
int log_variable;
char login[]="login";


void toLower(char str[]){//converts UPPERCASE to lowercase
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
}
//end of toLower

int compareStrings(char str1[], char str2[]){//compares 2 strings

    if(strlen(str1) == strlen(str2))
    {
        int i;
        for( i=0; i<strlen(str1); i++){
            if(str1[i] != str2[i])
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else return 0;
}


int loginCommand(char argument[]){//test function so far for login, myfind etc
    int fileDescr;

    pipe(fd);//defines the pipe

    switch(childpid=fork()){//switch statement to control parent and child

      case -1:
        perror("fork -1\n");
        exit(0);


      case 0://child
        close (fd[1]);
        char givenUsername[20];
        //open the config file and copy the username from it, assign to a variable, and then
        //compare it to readbuffer


        int nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));


        if(strcmp(readbuffer, login) == 0){
            printf("1: ");
            return 1;
        }

        else {
            printf("0: ");
            return 0;

        }
        exit(0);

      default:
        //parent
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], argument, sizeof(argument));
        wait(NULL)!=-1;
        exit(0);
    }
}

main(){
    char input[20];
    int logs;

    while(logs == 0){
        printf("Insert command: \n");
        scanf("%s", input);
        toLower(input);

        logs=(loginCommand(input));
        if(logs == 1) {printf("System accessed\n"); }
        if(logs == 0) {printf("This username doesnt exist\n"); }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

But my biggest question is that I input the value of "login", that is the same of the login variable above, the program responds correctly, but if I change that variable to of value of "loginloginlogin" let's say, and if I input from the console the same value, the program says that the value is incorrect. My assumption is that the program doesn't read the whole input from console, but I've changed the sizes of the strings, and still has the same behavior.

Can anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you *do* know of the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function?

Comment: Have you debugged it ? e.g. after your  `read(fd[0], readbuffer,`  print out what you read, enclosed in quotes so it's easier to spot whitespace, e.g. `printf("readData returned: %d '%s'\n", nbytes, readData);` Keep in mind though that C strings need to be nul terminated, so make sure they are. Also, **please format your code properly**.

Comment: I know of strcmp, I'll try that :\

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `wait` in a loop, you only have one child process, so `wait` will block until that single child exits. And after that, you exit the parent process, so the `loginCommand` function will never return to your `main` function.

Comment: I've edited the post with the updated code. But it still has the same behaviour. Seems that if my input string is more than 8 chars long, it wont "access the system", so to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
write(fd[1], argument, sizeof(argument));
```

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first character. Doing `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of the pointer and not the size of what it point so.

To get a the length of a string you need to use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Oh, and don't forget to use `strlen(argument) + 1` to also send the string terminator (alternatively terminate the string in the child process).